# Placement property OLEObject

Tags: excel, vba

This code below is not acting correctly, and I don't see the problem. 
When inserting an object with this code, it inserts it correctly. If I right click on the object it does set the placement property to move and size with the cell. However, the object is not actually mowing and sizing with the cell. I have done testing to make sure its not a problem with excel itself by inserting an object manually without the code and then right clicking and manually setting the placement property and that works fine. Could anyone give some insight to as why this code is working but not actually making the object move and size with the cell.

```
Public Sub insertFile()
        Dim oleObj As OLEObject

        'Select the cell in which you want to place the attachment
        Range("K9").Select

        'Get file path
        fpath = Application.GetOpenFilename("All Files,*.*", Title:="Select file")
        If LCase(fpath) = "false" Then Exit Sub

        'Insert file
        Set oleObj = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(Filename:=fpath, Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=True, DisplayAsIcon:=True, IconFileName:="excel.exe", IconIndex:=0, IconLabel:=extractFileName(fpath))
        oleObj.Placement = XlPlacement.xlMoveAndSize

    End Sub
```

Comment: From the way im interpreting this, you're saying that this works when the code is allowed to insert and set the placement of the object itself, but that it does not move and resize objects that already exist when you highlight that item by clicking on it and running this

Comment: If that's true then I'm not surprised, because the code is not meant to do that - you can change the code, however, if you want it to adjust files that already are on the sheet itself

Comment: Beg your pardon, but in what place of code you open a workbook?

Comment: @JohnnyL I don’t think he wants to open a workbook, just an OLEObject

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 Sorry guys took me a little to get back to this. So I have a button on my worksheet, I click it and can open a file to insert. It does insert the file to the workbook. At this point it does not size and move with the cell as intended. If I right click on the object to make sure that the placement property was set correctly it has been set by the above code correctly. Everything is implemented correctly to the object when it gets inserted however, the object itself is not moving and sizing with the cell as it is intended to even though placement property reflects that it should.

Comment: Can anyone help with this?